# define a class to store the information

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have got the user's information from contacts,and I want to store the information,so I define a new class:
my new class UserInfo.h file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface UserInfo : NSObject
{
    NSString *firstName;
    NSString *lastName;
    NSMutableArray *emailArray;
    UIImage *image;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *firstName;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *lastName;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *emailArray;
@property(nonatomic,retain)UIImage *image;
@end
```

my UserInfo.m file

```
#import "UserInfo.h"

@implementation UserInfo
@synthesize firstName;
@synthesize lastName;
@synthesize emailArray;
@synthesize image;

@end
```

in my view controller file ,I create a NSMutableArray to store the new class objects

```
NSMutableArray *m_AllUserArray;
```

my .m file,the fellowing code is in my loadView function:

```
m_AllUserArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


    for (int i = 0; i<CFArrayGetCount(nameArray); i++) {
        ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(nameArray, i);
        UserInfo *userinfo = [[UserInfo alloc]init];
        //----------get name
        userinfo.firstName = (NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person,kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
        userinfo.lastName = (NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);

        //----------get email
        ABMultiValueRef mails = (ABMultiValueRef)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
        for (int j = 0; j < ABMultiValueGetCount(mails); j ++) {
            NSString* emailContent = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(mails, j);
            if (emailContent != nil) {

                                [userinfo.emailArray addObject:emailContent];
            }
        }

        //-----------------get contact image
        NSData *imageData = (NSData*)ABPersonCopyImageData(person);
        //if there are no images in contact,will create default image instead
        UIImage *img;
        if (imageData == nil) {
            img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"friend_on_small_normal.png"];
        } else {
            img = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        }
        userinfo.image = img;
        //-------------------------------------
        [m_AllUserArray addObject:userinfo];


NSLog(@"userinfo.firstName:%@",userinfo.firstName);
        NSLog(@"userinfo.lastName:%@",userinfo.lastName);
        NSLog(@"userinfo.emailArray:%@",userinfo.emailArray);
        [userinfo release];
    }
```

but when I use the array,it's null,why?

```
for (int i=0; i<[m_AllUserArray count]; i++) {
            NSLog(@"%@",(UserInfo*)[m_AllUserArray objectAtIndex:i]);
            NSLog(@"lastName:%@",[(UserInfo*)[m_AllUserArray objectAtIndex:i] lastName]);
            NSLog(@"emailArray:%@",[[m_AllUserArray objectAtIndex:i] emailArray]);
            NSLog(@"email1:%@",[[[m_AllUserArray objectAtIndex:i] emailArray] objectAtIndex:0]);
            NSLog(@"email2:%@",[[[m_AllUserArray objectAtIndex:i] emailArray] objectAtIndex:1]);

        }
```

my log:

```
1970-01-11 10:57:08.-740 M[3291:307] <UserInfo: 0x2cbdd0>
1970-01-11 10:57:16.-585 M[3291:307] lastName:(null)
1970-01-11 10:57:23.-599 M[3291:307] emailArray:(null)
1970-01-11 11:52:00.-176 M[3291:307] email1:(null)
1970-01-11 11:52:04.-565 M[3291:307] email2:(null)
```

ps:
I have solved the problem,thank you ~~~~~

Comment: where is `m_AllUserArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];`? in `init`?

Comment: Please be specify while mentioning, since you have more than one array..

Comment: Please Use [m_AllUserArray addObject:userinfo.firstname]; instead of  
[m_AllUserArray addObject:userinfo] inside the For loop.
i am sure it'll work.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting some value in the line `(NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);`?

Comment: yes,I have print it' NSLog(@"userinfo.firstName:%@",userinfo.firstName);
        NSLog(@"userinfo.lastName:%@",userinfo.lastName);
        NSLog(@"userinfo.emailArray:%@",userinfo.emailArray);'

Comment: You have printed it right... Are you getting the correct values there?

Comment: thank you,I have know what's the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are talking about `emailArray` in `UserInfo` class.

You have not allocated that array. Initialize that array in `UserInfo` class `init` method. Else, create a new array and assign to that (`emailArray`) before adding elements to it.